# Linter Issue with Go-MongoDB Collections Find Query

Tags: mongodb, go, find, linter

My Go code has several statements of the sort:

```
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{{}})
```

and they work as expected but the linter complains when executing:

```
golangci-lint run ./... && ginkgo -r -cover
```

The linter displays the following error:

```
missing type in composite literal (typecheck)
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{{}})
```

Even when I provide key/value pairs the linter still complains. How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: An empty filter is `bson.D{}`, no need to provide an inner value. Also note that providing a type if it's the element type of the slice or map is unneeded, you might need the current version of your tool. Also note that this is unrelated to the mongo driver. Use keyed literals, e.g. `bson.D{{Key: "field", Value: "somevalue"}}`. Also note that if order doesn't matter, use `bson.M{}`, e.g. `bson.M{"field": "somevalue"}`

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the go compiler doesn't recognize the `bson.D` type. Check if you have initialized go modules.

```
go mod init
```

Either ways, do a tidy

```
go mod tidy
```

If should print the following output

```
go: finding module for package gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson
go: finding module for package go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
go: finding module for package go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options
...
```

Run the linter.

Comment: Unrelated but you shouldn't use `gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson` with `mongo-go`, but instead `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson` (the driver has its own BSON implementation).